# UIImageView not showing in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I am working on an `iOS` app using `5.1 iPhone SDK`. The app has 2 view controllers and a tab view controller. I am allocating a `UIImageView` from a `library` which is being linked to the app. The code to allocate the `UIIMageView` is being called from a function which is invoked after the app is initialised and launched. I use the code below to add the `UIImageView.`

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
[window addSubview:imgView];
[window bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
```

The problem is that the `imageView` is not showing up when the app is run. **I can't move the code out of the library or the function from where it is being called.**

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Maybe using protocol you can invoke a method which contains code snippet you posted in question in desired VC.

Comment: you need to add imageView in to your first loaded viewController then add it viewconroller into window

Comment: Are you giving the UIImageView an image to display?

Comment: I think you working for functionally animation plashscreen down to up animation this imageView right.. ?

Comment: Trying with my answer hope its help's you and its a propar way to do this stuff.I think you working for functionally animation plashscreen down to up animation this imageView right.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.window bounds]];
        imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [self.window addSubview:imgView];
        [self.window bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
        
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: hey iPatel your code working well but in log print this `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch` this way is not a proper bcz with Tabbarcontroller and navigationController in forther work facing some error

Answer (score -1):

In your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, that's the part where you set your first View Controller as your `rootViewController`. Which means that whatever you put on your first view controller, those are the things you will see first when your app runs.

I suggest your put your `UIImageView` on your `firstViewController`..

```
 //in your first View Controller file.
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

---

I'm not very sure if this tutorial link can help you, but since you mentioned that you have 2 view controllers, you might want to see this tutorial that shows how to change from your `first ViewController` to your `secondView.`

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2012/08/switching-to-different-views-with.html